# How do you view a printer's IP address on a school protected network?

Tags: networking, tcpip

How do you determine the ip address of a network printer whose menu options on the printer has been disabled by school admins?

Printing the configuration page does not show the TCP/IP information.

Pinging to the network printer name has also been disabled.

Comment: The School's admins should be able to provide you with that information.

Comment: Nothing like enough detail to answer. Can you print to it (is there a print queue or mapped printer to work with)? What kind of computers are you using? What printer model is it? Do you have a rough idea what the network range for printers is, and is it on the same broadcast domain as the computer? Why do you need the IP address? Is running a port scan against the school's acceptable use policy even if it's not intended to be malcious? How does pinging the name not work, have you tried by FQDN? Does it have a MAC address written on a label by the network connection?

Comment: Look for the MAC address on the printer. Print to the printer or ping your subnets broadcast address. Then check your arp table and look for the MAC address from the printer.

Comment: Do an `nslookup printername` and the DNS server should return the printername IP address. Unless, nslookup is disabled by your system administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a computer where the printer is mapped to, you should be able to see the ip address in the printer properties